# How do I properly cast IOHIDDevice when iterating through devices using IOKit in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift and I'm struggling to understand how "old-school Objective-C" stuff plays with Swift, specifically in programming a CLI for macOS.

I'm trying to list devices using IOKit but some casting to `IOHIDDevice` isn't working. The question is more about Swift pointer semantics (I guess) than IOKit itself.

I've got the following code to list devices:

```swift
import Foundation
import IOKit
import IOKit.hid

let matchingDict = IOServiceMatching(kIOHIDDeviceKey)
let hidManager = IOHIDManagerCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, IOOptionBits(kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone))
IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatching(hidManager, matchingDict)
IOHIDManagerOpen(hidManager, IOOptionBits(kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone))

let devices = IOHIDManagerCopyDevices(hidManager)

let s = devices as! CFSet
for obj in (s as Set) {
    print("type =", type(of: x))
    print("obj =", type(of: x))

    /* the following would fail: */
    // let x = obj as! IOHIDDevice
    // let v = IOHIDDeviceGetProperty(x, kIOHIDVendorIDKey)
}
```

So in that `for` loop, it prints `type = HIDDevice` for all entries.
As for the second print call, it prints something in the likes of `obj = <IOHIDDevice 0x103004340 [0x7ff843ec1190]  'ClassName=AppleUserUSBHostHIDDevice' Transport=USB VendorID=1133 ProductID=50479 Manufacturer=Logitech Product=USB Receiver PrimaryUsagePage=1 PrimaryUsage=2 ReportInterval=2000>` (always begins with `<IOHIDDevice ...`).

Firstly, I don't quite understand why the first one prints `HIDDevice` and the second `IOHIDDevice`. I can find the `IOHIDDeviceRef` type (which I understood has the "Ref" suffix dropped somehow) when searching the internet, but `HIDDevice` simply doesn't exist.

But my question is regarding the commented code: why (when uncommented) it crashes?
I mean, it compiles but will crash at runtime saying that the `obj as! IOHIDDevice` cast failed.
It I try to write the code as `obj as? IOHIDDevice`, XCode gives me the error `Conditional downcast to CoreFoundation type 'IOHIDDevice' will always succeed` and won't compile the code.
I just can't seem to grasp what that means and I guess there's some pointer trickery going on which I don't quite understand.

Could someone please point me in a direction on what I'm doing wrong here?